# How to model the Document class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm using a document class. The first time, it was for the common files with methods like New(), Open(), Save().

New() and Open() returns a IDocument. Save doesn't return anything.
As you can see in the diagram above.

[image]

In my program, it must use xml or zip file extension. For the xml files there's any problem, all the methods are for it. But I've got problems with zip file. I was planning to do this, when the program executes Open(), extract all the xml files from the zip and returns all the files. But my Open() only returns a document.

I was planning of creating another property called CanExtract(), but maybe this is not a good idea. I just want to create a good design and understandable.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Open Packaging Convention found in the System.IO.Packaging namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx)? It handles these two situations fairly well.

Comment: @sixlettervariables wow, it sounds interesting. so, do you think what I'm doing is not necessary?

Comment: I'm a beg, borrow, and steal sorta fellow. If you decline to use `System.IO.Packaging` directly, you can adopt their model or at least their idioms.

Comment: It might adjust your design a bit, but if the zip is a list of xml files, why not return a `List<IDocument>`? Or concatenate all the files in the zip to return one IDocument?

Comment: @OscarFimbres - Conceptually (given your requirements) is there any reason a single XML 'Document' file shouldn't be able to contain more than one 'Document'? Obviously this would require a minor tweak to your XML schema but then your XML files and your ZIP files would contain similar functionality.

Comment: Where would you have added the CanExtract()? You shouldn't let details (relevant to a single class only) creep up into your interface...

Comment: @codesparkle Oh that's true. I forgot that function. And the another one, I'll bear in mind.

Comment: Honestly, you don't need to add the [uml] tag to your question just because you have an image of a class diagram in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Change your Open() function to return an IEnumerable of IDocument:

```
public IEnumerable<IDocument> Open()
```

instead of

```
public IDocument Open()
```

Then when you open an xml file it returns an IEnumerable containing 1 IDocument and you can just use that one. When you open the zip file it returns all of the files in the zip as IDocuments inside the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing your return property to be a List. Then you can process the list of documents with the same code whether there is 1 or 20 files returned.

You could also add overloads for creation and saving that accept multiple files and, if those overloads are used, you could perform automatic zipping.